# Add padding for each cell in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a background color of gray, in the `RecyclerView`, I populate it with 3 different types of cells, with background color white.

I want to add padding to the left and right for all cells.

If I add the left and right padding to the RecyclerView however, it makes the background look funky and it shows gray bars since the padding is for `RecyclerView` rather than the cells.

Is there any way to do it without adding padding to each type of cell?

Comment: Instead of adding padding to RecyclerView, try adding directly to the item_layout which contains item for list.

Comment: @Rajasekhar, I have 4 types of items that go in this RecyclerView. Is it fine to add it to each item?

Comment: Since you have said you only need padding to left and right side, identify the cells which are left and right to the parent, and then apply padding to them. Instead of theory, post and show us layout which you have tried creating the design you need. It would be helpful to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding the padding to each cell is certainly ok.

If you want it to be easily maintainable and for all values to be the same. Add a padding resource to `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="recycler_view_h_padding">16dp</dimen>
```

And then apply the padding to each cell with the reference

```
android:paddingStart="@dimen/reycler_view_h_padding"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/recycler_view_h_padding"
```